# Is it possible to upload files to a custom list in SharePoint online using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm currently creating application that can upload files to a SharePoint custom list, is this possible? If so can someone share a link where I can use and study?

NOTE: I wanted to upload the file to a **Custom List** not a Document Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File can be host as attachment for list item.

```
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Listtitle");
                ListItem item = list.GetItemById(itemid);
                var attachment = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
                string filePath = @"C:\Lee\template.xlsx";
                attachment.FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath); 
                attachment.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
                Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachment);
                context.Load(att);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```